# Show comments to a question, when editing that question with less than 2K reputation

Tags: feature-request, editing

When I edit a question, this is often in response to a suggestion in the comments. For this reason it would be very helpful if I could see the comments at the same time in the window where I am editing my question.

Comment: I take it you mean without scrolling? http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye6BS.png

Comment: @muru OP hasn't enough reputation to do "in-place" edits like 2K+ users, so when he tries to edit the editor is opened in another page, which doesn't include the comments at the bottom

Comment: @kos But does this apply to editing one's own post? That's how I read it at first.

Comment: I found it pretty annoying when I had less than 2K reputation, and I still find this pretty annoying on community where I have less than 2K reputation, expecially when I'm trying to address a comment

Comment: @muru Exactly :) I'll tell you in a minute, gonna try this on U&L where I have 1K~ reputation

Comment: @muru Yes, same thing even on own posts